# Заполнение массивов без известной длины

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

Возникла необходимость создать массив или подобие ему в него будут входить 20 подмассивов или списков длина которых неизвестна и в цикле будут распределяться по ним значения

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос? Вам нужно уточнить с чем именно у вас возникли сложности, конкретизировать проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# есть изумительная вещь – коллекции.

```
// объявляете список массивов (в данном случае массивы объектов) 
List<object[]> arrays = new List<object[]();
// а вот так добавляете в список новый массив
object[] objects = new object[10];
arrays.Add(objects);
```